# changing the CSS of the droppable element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css, html5-canvas

I am having a list of products. Some of them should be dropped to a specific point. With the others, anything else should happen (not important for now, just to let you know, I am having a randomly amount of dropped elements)

The problem now is, I have an image for each element. This image should be visible as soon as the appropriate element is dropped to the correct position. Since the for loop is finished at the point the user can interacte with the programm, i is always 30. Here is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  if (i > (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))) {
      $('#listProducts').append('<span class="invisibleImageContainer' + i + '"><img class="invisibleImage-' + products[i].toString() + '" src="img/products/' + products[i] + '" style="display:none"/></span>')
    } else {
      $('#listProducts').append('<p>anythingElse</p>');
    }   

$('.droppableClassName' + i).droppable({
    accept: '.drag-' + products[i],
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(".invisibleImage-" + products[i].toString()).css("display", "block");
      } //END drop function
   }); //END droppable
} //END for Schleife
```

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with the code you have so far?

Comment: You have incorrect quotes all throughout your span creation. You also can't just create elements in JavaScript and expect them to appear. They have to be create as strings or via a proper method, and then appended. You are only appending in the else case.

Comment: sorry, I have been to fast for the demonstration code, in real i am having the append of course :-) I have added it to the demonstration code

Comment: It could be a result of your random generator. You are getting a number between 0 and 9. It's possible that `i` is always evaluating as greater than the random number you get. This will certainly be the case for `i > 9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an immediately executed function that passes in the current i value. You will see this pattern quite often in cases like this. Something like:

```
$('.droppableClassName' + i).droppable({
    accept: '.drag-' + products[i],
    drop: (function(idx) {
        return function(event, ui) {
            $(".invisibleImage-" + products[idx].toString()).css("display", "block");
          } //END drop function
        })(i) //Self executing anonymous function. Pass i to it.
   }); //END droppable
} //E
```

Passing i to a self executing function creates a copy of it, so for each draggable object, you are referencing the local copy idx rather than the changing value i.

Comment: wow that sounds like exactly what I needed. How does the programm know what idx is? Is it because of the i which is passed to it?

Comment: @BrigitteFellner Yes that's right. Take a close at what is happening - it takes some getting used to but once you understand it's a very useful technique. You are running a function which takes in i as a parameter. That function then returns another function (the draggable one) which uses idx. idx is the value of i passed in but because it gets copied when it is passed to the function, it does not get incremented when the for loop continues.